# Crash:systemd-journald:failed to write entry. ignoring input/output. systemd-journald:failed to rotate /var/log/journal/ read only file system

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, crash

I have a Hp laptop, dual boot, running windows 10,and Ubuntu 18.04LTS.
Recently I have been facing issue, that Ubuntu suddenly crashes and shows error of this type [Link of the image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HSrocrLyivQw7fsaXW5O7xE-6kgUXsO2/view?usp=drivesdk) and another time this type of error [link of another image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HOzq0cMCdFiyligdCMVKtDEHLrEYa9xg/view?usp=drivesdk).

I am a newbie and don't know what is causing this error, still I have a speculation that might be my HDD is causing this, my laptop has become very slow, its 3+ years old and recently ran the SMART Test, the test result was OK, and bad sector count was 25168. Please help.

Comment: Look up how to run a SMART Test on your hard drive. A read-only filesystem error can occur for several hardware-related reasons (not an Ubuntu problem), but most commonly when the drive is starting to die.

Comment: Thanks, for replying, I have attached the results of SMART test, [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m8AXnA5VZVdZ0S175utxR2NEylMmxj2N/view?usp=sharing), [another image link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N_s9kXsgA09l4niogm8A1cRD0oqlbANd/view?usp=sharing), so is it really because the HDD is dying or maybe some other issue?